# Android Studio: how to remove navigation bar in android app to get a full screen view?

Tags: java, android

How do I remove the navigation bar to get Full Screen View?

[image]

So far I've tried setting the theme using:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

and

```
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

in styles.xml
and

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

in activity_main.xml
and i also tried

```
ActionBar ac = getSupportActionBar();
ac.hide();
```

even tried

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

in my MainActivity.java but this only made action bar to disappear. I have

been trying for a few days now but can't figure this out.

Comment: That's not an action bar, that's the on-screen navigation buttons :D

Comment: OMG that explains so much!! thank you!!

Comment: That's what the actionbar is: https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html . Consider always referring to the documentation when in doubt.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try! call it in onCreate()

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

And

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
if (hasFocus) {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}
}
```

**UPDATE 07/08/2023 Fixed Deprecated**

```
 fun hideSystemUIOnCreate() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    } else {
        window?.let {
            WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(it, false)
        }
    }
 }


 fun hideSystemUIOnWindowFocusChanged(view: View) {
    //view is rootView (ex: binding.root)
    val window = window ?: return
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        // Tell the window that we want to handle/fit any system windows
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        val controller = view.windowInsetsController
        // Hide the keyboard (IME)
        controller?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.ime())
        // Sticky Immersive is now ...
        controller?.systemBarsBehavior =
            WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
        // When we want to hide the system bars
        controller?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars())
    } else {
        //noinspection
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        // For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            // Hide the nav bar and status bar
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
    }
 }
```

Comment: It works - is it somehow possible to keep it away so that it does not pop up again, when sliding up with the fingers.

Answer (score -1):

you need fullscreen layout try this:

`getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN`);

add it in the onCreate of the Activity that you wanted to see fullscreen.

Comment: works temporarily although when the screen is touched it comes back and doesn't go away again.